# Libgdx Mp3 Decoder

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, mp3

Ive been trying for the best part of today to get the libgdx mp3 decoder to work. I have been following the tutorial that can be found here: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?cat=18

However Android Studio cannot find the MP3Decoder class, or Jlayer for that matter. I have also tried to find Mpg123 decoder, to no avail.

Has anyone got any similar experiences, I am new to the libgdx environment so i dont really know what I'm doing.

Furthermore when Android Studio proposes I add library 'com.badlogicgames.jlayer:jlayer:1.0.1-gdx' to classpath, after I alt+enter the MP3Decoder class highlighted in red nothing happens on click, gradle just syncs.

Any advice on importing the MP3 decoder?

Comment: That tutorial is from when LibGDX had an audio extension, which has since been retired. You might be able to find the old gdxaudio source code to see how it was implemented and update it to work with modern Libgdx.

Comment: Ah that would make sense. Thank you